# CSS3 image animation inside a div element stretches

Tags: html, css

I want to place a large image that would be "scrolling" up & down inside a `<div>` element.
The problem is that the images' size is stretched to the size of the `#animation-win` div element.
The images' height is greater than 300px, so that is the reason why I want to scroll it up&down so it can appear in its original size within the 300px div element.
Can it be done? Thank you very much.

This is the html:

```
<div id="animation-win">
 <div class="anim">
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#animation-win {

    background:#000;
    position: relative;
    width:900px;
    height:300px;
}

.anim
{

     background-image:url('../images/picture1.jpg');
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     position:absolute;
     animation:cssanim 5s infinite;
     animation-direction:alternate;

     /* Safari and Chrome */
     -webkit-animation:cssanim 5s infinite;
     -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
}

@keyframes cssanim
{
     0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
     100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssanim /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%{
    background-image:url('../images/picture1.jpg'); 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px; 
    top:0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
100% {
    background-image:url('../images/picture1.jpg');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px; 
    bottom:549px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dunno, this seems okay to me : http://jsfiddle.net/BdU7W/

Comment: I'am not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to show an large image through an smaller 'viewport' div?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, if you add an image for exaple with the size of 900x900px, it will be stretched.
At the first second as you run the page, the visible part of the image should be 900x300 - the first 300 pixel rows of the image

Comment: @veelen is it maybe clearer through my explanation for TheDarkKnight?

Comment: Because you have height: 300px;, easy to reproduce - if you set height: 900px; it does not strecth.

Comment: You can do it but its fugly (http://jsfiddle.net/BdU7W/1/). Does it have to be a background image? It would be simpler to have the image in a fixed height div and then animate the image's position within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% of 300px is 300px. Set the real height in `cssanim` - then it wont stretch (here 900px as mentioned above) you can let the height 300px be in `#animation-win`.

```
0%{
    background-image:url('1.gif'); 
    width:100%;
    height:900px; /* <---- */
    left:0px; 
    top:0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
100% {
    background-image:url('1.gif');
    width:100%;
    height:900px; /* <---- */
    left:0px; 
    bottom:300px; /* <--- so the area not get entirely black in a long moment */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

Note : tested with `1.gif` which is `233 x 282` px, so above should be valid along with your image also. jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dLGBX/ with a random wikipaedia-image.